# Game crashes when I try to use the features of a b2Body -- why?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

My app crashes when I try to use the features of `b2Body` from within my `NSObject` class.

Here is the interface of my class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Box2D.h"
#import "GLES-Render.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "HelloWorldScene.h"


@interface Magnet : NSObject {
    b2Body* body;
}
@property (readwrite,assign) b2Body* body;
@end
```

And here is how I declare it in HelloWorldScene.h:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "GLES-Render.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Magnet.h"

@class Magnet;

@interface HelloWorld : CCLayer {
    b2World* world;
    GLESDebugDraw *m_debugDraw;
    Magnet *magnet;
}
```

And here is how I access the `b2Body` in `magnet`, in HelloWorldScene.mm:

```
b2BodyDef bodyDef2;
bodyDef2.type = b2_staticBody;

bodyDef2.position.Set(300/PTM_RATIO, 150/PTM_RATIO);
bodyDef2.userData = sprite2;
magnet.body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef2);

// Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
//b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
b2CircleShape dynamicBox2;

//dynamicBox.SetAsBox(1.0f, 1.0f);//These are mid points for our 1m box
dynamicBox2.m_radius = 0.49;
// Define the dynamic body fixture.
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef2;

fixtureDef2.shape = &dynamicBox2;   
fixtureDef2.density = 1.3f;
fixtureDef2.friction = 1.0f;

magnet.body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef2);
```

Is there any problem with my code?

I'm receiving a SIGABRT in the Box2D source files, in the `CreateFixture()` function. What should I do?

Sorry about the mess, here is the backtrace:

```
    (gdb) bt
    #0  0x0002f35c in b2Body::CreateFixture (this=0x0, def=0xbfffd360) at b2Body.cpp:141
    #1  0x00004f7e in -[HelloWorld loadLevel:] (self=0x5544770, _cmd=0xfbc7c, level=1) at HelloWorldScene.mm:255
    #2  0x0000573d in -[HelloWorld init] (self=0x5544770, _cmd=0x4ffd774) at HelloWorldScene.mm:140
    #3  0x0009d7b1 in +[CCNode node] (self=0x147100, _cmd=0xfc558) at CCNode.m:231
    #4  0x0000377d in +[HelloWorld scene] (self=0x147100, _cmd=0xfb61c) at HelloWorldScene.mm:39
    #5  0x000036d7 in -[MagnetSpillAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] (self=0x680b9f0, _cmd=0xca40a3, application=0x5511370) at MagnetSpillAppDelegate.mm:96
    #6  0x008b1ce2 in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] ()
    #7  0x008b3d88 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] ()
    #8  0x008be617 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
    #9  0x008b6abf in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
    #10 0x008bbf2e in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
    #11 0x029ca992 in PurpleEventCallback ()
    #12 0x0147d944 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
    #13 0x013ddcf7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
    #14 0x013daf83 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
    #15 0x013da840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
    #16 0x013da761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
    #17 0x008b37d2 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
    #18 0x008bfc93 in UIApplicationMain ()
    #19 0x00002cc4 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff058) at main.m:13
```

Comment: What does the console say? Usually the console provides you with more information about the SIGABRT exception, like unknown selector etc.

Comment: Hmm.. The console gives me a warning: "Warning: the current language does not match this frame."
Current language:  auto; currently c++" How can this be solved?

Comment: Post the backtrace of the crash.

Comment: It is crashing in `loadLevel`.  Post that code.  If the code you have posted is *that* code, then -- most likely -- it is because you are passing garbage to CreateFixture().

Comment: Yes the code I have posted basically is _that_ code. So why does the b2Body property of the class become garbage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the crash, it is hard to say specifically what is going wrong.

However, that code is rife with potential for crashes.

- you are using structures that are on the stack, not allocated.  If the scope of that code goes away before you are done with those structures, it'll lead to crashes and undefined behavior.
- you aren't initializing all the fields in those structures; the remaining values will be in an undefined state.   Since it is impossible to differentiate an uninitialized `float32` from an initialized `float32`, that is bound to eventually lead to problems.
- you are setting up structures on the stack that have references to other structures on the stack;  another form of the first point, but should be called out because it makes it doubly easy to leak pointers to the stack.

---

Line 141 of b2Body::CreateFixture() is an assert:

```
    b2Assert(m_world->IsLocked() == false);
```

Is your world locked?  Looks like it shouldn't be.

Comment: this is everything in the debug log: Warning: the current language does not match this frame.
Current language:  auto; currently c++
kill
quit
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: It works when i access the same b2Body functions with a body outside the "Magnet" class, but when its inside it crashes, do I have to init it inside the class or doesnt that matter? Im really stuck on this.

Comment: If the debugger is giving you the `(gdb)` prompt, then your app crashed and there is a backtrace.  You need to post that, please.   Your code is currently allocating everything on the stack save for the two Create() calls that look OK.  There needs to be more information to draw more of a conclusion.

Comment: Ok, here is the backtrace (I think): "May 16 12:09:15 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.MagnetSpill[0xd13a]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3794 (24506):3
May 16 12:09:15 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.MagnetSpill[0xd13a]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3202 (24506):10
May 16 12:09:15 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.MagnetSpill[0xd13a]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.

Comment: May 16 12:09:15 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.yourcompany.MagnetSpill[0xd13a]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
May 16 12:09:15 unknown SpringBoard[29] <Warning>: Application 'MagnetSpill' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11"

Comment: That isn't the backtrace;  if you are stopped in the debugger, the `bt` command will give you the backtrace.  If the app crashed on a device w/o the debugger, then there is probably a crash log in the organizer window.   Edit your question and add the crash log.

Comment: Ok, now it has been added to the original post.

Comment: No worries -- I'm not familiar with Box2D (That line o' code & the function decl being the sum total of what I've read).  I'd guess that you need to lock the world prior to setting things up or something.  At this point, this search (http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=box2d+lock+world) is probably more useful than my input.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and kindness. + rep (or whatever)